# Generic SQL and Software migration platform

Tags: database, database-migration, liquibase

I saw a lot of different database migrations tools ([here](https://awesomeopensource.com/projects/database-migrations))
Which make me asking

1. is there some generic database migration platform that supports SQL and executable (any language) migration tools corresponding to the language?
   Let's say I want some procedure in any language to be made. Why do I need to choose a platform in my current project's language?
2. In general, there are general migration platforms for software without database relations?
   Upgrade and downgrade software procedures are the same. Why not use the same pattern?

Comment: This is too general for a sensible answer. Also, StackOverflow explicitly disallows questions which ask to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library,", see item 4 at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .

Comment: For a "migration tool", you'll need some way to store state, or decide which version a system is currently at, in order to decide which upgrade migrations need applying. For a SQL migration tool like Liquibase, it generally uses one or more reserved tables in the database itself to store that info. That limits the "generalisation" of that pattern to SQL databases only. It's not really clear what other parts you would want to preserve in a "generalisation" of this tool. Does "git" meet your requirements?